# Countdown timer in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've searched other questions and google/YouTube, and from what I've found, it seems that this is possible, but I have not found this exact use case as an example to pull from.  And to preface, I have a *slight* working knowledge of coding, but not a whole lot.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: I want to create a countdown timer in Google Sheets with 2 possible functions (depending on the use case):
1) where I can put in the end date the timer counts down to, either in a specific cell or in the code itself.
2) using a dynamic date (i.e., 30 days from the date the timer was created)

So where I have gotten stuck... I tried using script.google.com and pasted this script for a countdown timer that I found online:

```js
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

But when I run the code, I get "Syntax error. (line 7, file "countdown")".

What modifications do I need to make to the code to get it to work?  Or am I using an overcomplicated code to create the timer, and there  is a much easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you save it as HTML? Or as JS?
Because you should save it as .html since your Javascript is within  tags instead of it being a separate file.
The code you pulled from w3schools is just a snippet, I've added   and  tags and it works just fine.
In your example snippet you also pasted it into the Javascript box instead of the HTML box.
Try this example, it's exactly the code you had!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
```

Another way of doing it is to actually separate your javascript and html into separate files to keep it cleaner and to keep scripts and HTML separated. For example name your HTML index.html and your script timer.js
Then in your HTML, instead of the big blob of script, you simply do 
`<script src="/timer.js"></script>`

```js
// Save this as for example timer.js

// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!-- Save this as index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<!-- Load the Javascript from a separate file called timer.js -->
<script src="/timer.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @bdbdbd! So I'm sure you can tell that I have limited knowledge in this realm.  :)

So I went and created both the js and html files. My followup questions... when saving the timer.js to the script.google.com, it has the option of .gs and not .js. Is that okay?

When I try to run the script, it gives me the error "ReferenceError: "setInterval" is not defined. (line 5, file "timer.js")"  Can I set a specific cell in the google sheet to set the interval?

Comment: @Mackensie Ooh I did not read/realize you were using Google scripts, and I have no experience with them. Saving it as .gs should be fine and it should still work like Javascript. The problem is that setInterval is a method that's available within browsers, so it's broserJS. Google script is slightly different and doesn't have a setInterval function available. I Believe there are some alternatives for it but you'd have to Google that I'm afraid. Like "setInterval alternative Google scipts" or something. Like I said, I don't have any experience with that at all.